# Getting different results on filter when using CurrentMember. Axis issue?

Tags: sql-server, mdx, business-intelligence

I work in education, and I'm trying to find the Term that a student graduated -- or to use University lingo, was conferred.

If I use the following MDX, I get the *right* result, which happens to be Fall of last year.

```
select 
filter(
    [Term].[Term].[Term],
    (
        [Student].[Student].[Student Dimension Type].&[Student].&[123456],
        [Measures].[Degree Conferred Count]
    ) > 0
) on 0
from [Enrollment Analytics]
```

If I swap out the explicit student member with currentmember, and throw student on another axis, I get Fall, Summer, and Spring for the last 2 years.

```
select 
    filter(
        [Term].[Term].[Term],
        (
            [Student].[Student].currentmember,
            [Measures].[Degree Conferred Count]
        ) > 0
    ) on 0,
    [Student].[Student].[Student Dimension Type].&[Student].&[123456] on 1
from [Enrollment Analytics]
```

If anyone's got the time, could you explain how these 2 statements are processed differently? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When processign the Axis 0, I guess there's [Student].currentMember yet, so the .defaultMember of this hierarchy is going to be used; so you'll get a filter set based on that default member value.

I think adding a where clause (that is defining the current member) :

```
where [Student].[Student].[Student Dimension Type].&[Student].&[123456]
```

is what you're looking for.